# How to get days from Epoch january 1 1970 in datetime.datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

I am using fatsecret REST api and the api specifies that I need to get the number of days in `dateint` format.

I have tried all the posts on stack overflow I could find but all the solutions provided turn the datetime in seconds to an int. Which gives me this error

`datetime.datetome.now()` returns the date like this:
 2018-04-23 01:59:45.451741

If I try to strformat the date I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I just need the number of days from january 1, 1970 in a `datetime.datetime` format. Thanks

Comment: This looks to require some hardcore programming skills.

Comment: If this is considered hardcore for you @Cryptopat ....wow. The Fatsecret api docs are pretty confusing but `datetime.datetime.now()` was exactly what I needed. The weird part is the function is supposed to receive "The number of days since January 1 1970 in dateInt format", apparently `2018-04-23 01:59:45.451741` is dateInt format.

Comment: (...) `date +%s` `date --help`

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert `datetime.datetime.now()` into a `float`because it has characters like `-` and `:`. Instead to calculate the number of days use:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date(2018, 4, 22) #Today's date
past_date = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1) #Jan 1 1970
print ((today - past_date).days)
```

Comment: It converted to float just fine but in the api helper function the float I created was subtracted from a date which caused the error. `datetime.datetime.now()` alone worked perfectly. Apparently `datetime.datetime.now()` is dateInt format.